# How to fit an algorithm into a template?

Tags: two-column, algorithms, algorithm2e

My aim is to fit this long single-line algorithm into a double column page lay out, just as it is shown in the below, in 3 different lines, but I cannot use `\State` and I do not know why and how can I make this to happen.

```
  \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

     \begin{algorithm}[H]

     \caption{Computing Levenshtein edit distance }
     \label{editComputing}

    $D(i,j)=min{D(i-1,j-1)+\gamma(A<i> \to B<j>),
                D(i-1,j)+ \gamma(A<i> \to \Lambda),
                D(i,j-1) +\gamma(\Lambda \to B<j>)}$

    \end{algorithm}
\begin{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the `[H]`ere specifier, since it's not allowed in `twocolumn` mode by-design. Also, I've used some `\phantom`s to provide the appropriate layout of the function across three lines.

Note that `\State` is used by [`algorithmicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx)'s `algpseudocde` package, not [`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e). Instead, `algorithm2e` uses an end-of-line `\;` *without* a `\State`.

In order to make the math display fit, it's better to use `\langle`...`\rangle` rather than `<`...`>`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{algorithm2e,lipsum,amsmath}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{algorithm}
  \DontPrintSemicolon
  \caption{Computing Levenshtein edit distance }
  $D(i,j) = \min\bigl\{D(i-1,j-1) + \gamma(A\langle i\rangle \to B\langle j\rangle),$\;
  $\phantom{D(i,j) = \min\bigl\{} D(i-1,j) + \gamma(A\langle i\rangle \to \Lambda),$\;
  $\phantom{D(i,j) = \min\bigl\{} D(i,j-1) + \gamma(\Lambda \to B\langle j\rangle)\bigr\}$\;
\end{algorithm}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: sorry for the late response, carried away with something else. When I use your code in my code, the caption is not aligned with the formula. Moreover, it is printed at the top part of next page, unlike what you have shown in this answer. Do you mind to let me know what could go wrong?

Answer (score 2):

i don't know any reason not to use `align*` for this; requires `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\noindent Some text preceding.
\begin{algorithm}
  \DontPrintSemicolon
  \caption{Computing Levenshtein edit distance }
  \abovedisplayskip=0pt
  \begin{align*}
  D(i,j) = \min\bigl\{& D(i-1,j-1) + \gamma(A\langle i\rangle \to B\langle j\rangle),\\
  & D(i-1,j) + \gamma(A\langle i\rangle \to \Lambda),\\
  & D(i,j-1) + \gamma(\Lambda \to B\langle j\rangle)\bigr\}
  \end{align*}
\end{algorithm}

\noindent Some text following.
  \begin{align*}
  D(i,j) = \min\bigl\{& D(i-1,j-1) + \gamma(A\langle i\rangle \to B\langle j\rangle),\\
  & D(i-1,j) + \gamma(A\langle i\rangle \to \Lambda),\\
  & D(i,j-1) + \gamma(\Lambda \to B\langle j\rangle)\bigr\}
  \end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

the line `\abovedisplayskip=0pt` is included to eliminate excessive space
at the top of the algorithm block; this does not happen automatically in
a "restricted" environment.  (the second instance of the code is included
to demonstrate that this adjustment does not persist.)

**edit:**
the space above *and* below the algorithm defaults to `\smallskip`.  the command
provided to change this is `\SetAlgoSkip{...}` and suggested values are `medskip` or `bigskip`.  notice the absence of the backslash; these are not control
sequences, and cannot be substituted by actual dimension values.

Comment: Maybe this is just me, but I cant see any difference the two formulas.

Comment: @user3049183 -- there's no difference in the *formulas*.  the difference is in the amount of space between the formulas and the preceding text.

Comment: Which of these two spacing is recommended? I mean, since it seems the formula belongs to an academic article, which of these two spacing scheme looks more appropriate?

Comment: the goal is to have the same spacing above the algorithm that begins with the `align` as it would be if the algorithm begins with text.  the space above a "text" algorithm is slightly larger than the space between text and ordinary display math, and is "correct" from that point of view in this example.  if the space from the `align` hadn't been removed for the algorithm, the space would have been as large as those two spaces added together -- *much* too large.

Comment: I see. I realized that the caption has very thin space with the text in the next paragraph. How to fix this?